# How to solve this algebra problem related to Pythagorean triplets?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

If $a^2+b^2=c^2 $ and $a+b+c=1000$ where a,b,c are positive integers, find the product $abc$.

First I tried this:
$$(a+b)^2=(1000-c)^2$$
$$a^2+b^2+2ab=c^2+1000^2-2000c$$
$$2ab=1000^2-2000c$$

But I didn't know how to proceed from here so I tried a different method.
I tried to solve this by using the formula that generates Pythagorean triples: $m^2+1, m^2-1, 2m$ so I got:
$$m^2+1 +m^2-1 +2m = 1000$$
$$2m^2+2m=1000$$
$$m^2+m=500$$

Now if I solve the quadratic equation
$$m^2+m-500=0$$

then I'm getting an irrational answer. So how do I solve this?

Comment: This is an old question. For a solution see for example [here](https://www.quora.com/If-a-2+b-2-c-2-and-a+b+c-1000-what-is-the-answer-of-abc), or see the duplicate.

Comment: Triples are $m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2$. Why do you take $n=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not really hard to prove that $\left(\text{a},\text{b},\text{c}\right)\in\left\{\left(200,375,425\right),\left(375,200,425\right)\right\}$.

Comment: And it is also well known at this site here.